# switch fragments with button (with NavigationDrawer)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a `NavigationDrawer` which I use to switch between `Fragment`s. What i would like to do is have a button in one of my fragments which acts as a 'shortcut' to another `Fragment` in the `NavigationDrawer`.

In the `NavigationDrawer` I switch fragments like this:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

public void selectItem(int position) { 

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        String fragmentTag = String.valueOf(position);

        FragmentBase fragment = (FragmentBase) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        if (null == fragment) { 
            fragment = createFragmentByPosition(position);
        }
        if (null == fragment)
            return;

        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag); 
        }

        if (mCurrentFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(mCurrentFragment);
        }
        mCurrentFragment = fragment;
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mNoterActivities[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    private FragmentBase createFragmentByPosition(int position) { // FragmentBase just extends Fragment
        FragmentBase fragment = null;

        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

        } else if (position == 1) { // Reminder
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

        }

        return fragment;
    }
```

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. I tried getting an instance of the NavigationDrawer class and then calling selectItem with the desired position, but this doesn't work as it gives an error "no view found".

In the NavigationDrawer class:

```
public Navigation_Drawer getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new Navigation_Drawer();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

In FragmentB (position 1):

```
//onClick
    Navigation_Drawer nd = new Navigation_Drawer().getInstance(); 
             nd.selectItem(0); // Try to go to FragmentA
```

This seems far too simple so no wonder it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, on `selectItem` method, using `add` method instead of `replace` method:

```
public void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    String fragmentTag = String.valueOf(position);

    FragmentBase fragment = (FragmentBase) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    if (null == fragment) {
        fragment = createFragmentByPosition(position);
    }
    if (null == fragment)
        return;

    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
    } else {
        // fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag); 
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
    }

    if (mCurrentFragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.hide(mCurrentFragment);
    }
    mCurrentFragment = fragment;
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mNoterActivities[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Second, `getInstance` method in `Navigation_Drawer` should not create a new `Navigation_Drawer` when `instance` is null, set instance to `this` in `onCreate` in `Navigation_Drawer`, then return `instance` when call `getInstance`:

```
private static Navigation_Drawer mInstance;

public static Navigation_Drawer getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mInstance = this;
    // other codes here:
}
```

The id to the `QuickNoteFragment` is 0, and to `PendViewPager` is 1.  You can turn to `PendViewPager` in `QuickNoteFragment`:

```
Navigation_Drawer.getInstance().selectItem(1);
```

-

#### update1: how to pass data to fragment:

`QuickNoteFragment` and `HistoryFragement` have the same parent Class: `FragmentBase`, we add a method named `onDataIn` to receive data:

```
public class FragmentBase extends Fragment {

    public void function onDataIn(Object data) {
    }
}
```

We should change `selectItem`, add a paraments to receive data:

```
public void selectItem(int position, Object data) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    String fragmentTag = String.valueOf(position);

    FragmentBase fragment = (FragmentBase) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    if (null == fragment) {
        fragment = createFragmentByPosition(position);
    }
    if (null == fragment)
        return;

    // call onDataIn() method.
    fragment.onDataIn(data);

    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
    } else {
        // fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag); 
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
    }

    if (mCurrentFragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.hide(mCurrentFragment);
    }
    mCurrentFragment = fragment;
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mNoterActivities[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

In order to make `selectItem` compatible, we should add a overloaded `selectItem` method.

```
public void selectItem(int postion) {
    selectItem(position, null);
}
```

In this way, we do not need to change the old code where called `selectItem` and did not need pass a data to fragement.

Comment: Thanks srain. I have another small question - if I use this when I press a button, I do I pass data from the fragment with the button, to the fragment I want. on start(), on resume() are not called, so there is no way for me to receive intents.  Maybe ifVisibleToUser will work. I will try.

Comment: I gave an some code about passing data to fragment, hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you - I have that running, but I don't get how to retrieve the data when I'm in the other fragment.  I have added `Navigation_Drawer.getInstance().selectItem(0, "mytext");` in HistoryFragment

Comment: You can overwrite the `onDataIn` method to process data int the fragment in which you want to retrieve the data.